# Command Prompt netstat response

Tags: command-line, vnc, netstat

I was trying to check if any VNC is turned on so I tried

```
netstat -an | find "ESTABLISHED" | find ":5900"
```

and

```
netstat -an | find "ESTABLISHED" | find ":5800"
```

I got some feedback

```
 TCP    127.0.0.1:9443    127.0.0.1:58008    ESTABLISHED
```

What does this feedback mean? From [How to check if anyone is connected to my laptop through TightVNC?](https://superuser.com/questions/1409740/how-to-check-if-anyone-is-connected-to-my-laptop-through-tightvnc), I understand that maybe a VNC is turned on but the address I got is a localhost address which is something I do not understand. Someone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look closely. 
It’s port 58008. 
This is just some random local TCP connection
that has nothing to do with 5800 or 5900 (i.e., nothing to do with VNC),
but it contains `:5800` as a string, and that’s what `find` looks at.

A more reliable test would be to use `find ":5800 "` and `find ":5900 "`
(with trailing spaces).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So it has nothing to do with VNC? Cause from the other post, it means that there might be a VNC established in my computer.

Comment: I added a comment to the answer to the other question.

Comment: Alright! Thank you so much, you're a lifesaver.